# Would a physical keyboard prevent a inputAccessoryView from appearing?

Tags: ios

I've added an inputAccessoryView to the iOS keyboard for certain UITextFields in my app.  This accessory view provides essential functionality to the user (some buttons that are displayed nowhere else in my app).  My understanding (which could be completely wrong) is that if a physical (bluetooth) keyboard is available iOS will not clutter the screen with the software keyboard.  If that's the case, users of my app with a physical keyboard will be missing some functionality and I'll need to account for that.  So the first question is, is that something I have to worry about?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input accessory view should appear at the bottom of the screen if a physical keyboard is used, so they will still be able to access the functionality. If you want to try this in the simulator, check the `Simulate Hardware Keyboard` option under the `Hardware` menu.

Comment: Right you are.  Thank you.  (And thanks to the clever Apple folks.)

Comment: Huh, the reported keyboard size provided with the keyboardWillAppear isn't "right" when there is a physical keyboard.  Instead of being just the height of the keyboardAccessory (or zero) it appears to be the size of the software keyboard that doesn't actually appear.  So my code for moving the text view up when it would be covered by the rising software keyboard also kicks in when there's a hardware keyboard.  Is that other people's experience?

Comment: That is rather strange. The `keyboardWillAppear` notification should not even be firing when there is a physical keyboard present. I do not have any way of testing this on a physical device, though, so it may be an inconsistency with the simulator.

Comment: Maybe someone with a real keyboard can test it for us and report back.

Comment: Really old thread, but this is the behaviour I'm seeing. If you have an inputAccessoryView, then the keyboardWillAppear notification is posted when you have a hardware keyboard. And even in iOS 7, the keyboard size is as if the software keyboard is there even though it isn't. Any workarounds for this?